# How to effectively use pandas with python mpi4py parallelism?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi4py

I am trying to do some operation on pandas data frames in different directories. The steps are-

1. Go to each particular directory and search for a specific file using glob
2. Perform some editing using a bash script and convert it into a more reasonable data file
3. Next, convert the data into a 'CSV and start using pandas thereafter
4. Finally, using multiprocessing (poo. map) performs the operation using multiple processors.

However, the problem is given the huge size (650065 rows) of the data frame it is still slow with multiprocessing. I was wondering if anyone knows how to effectively replace this with mpi4py.

Here is the code-

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import glob, os
import mpi4py
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

# get number of processors and processor rank
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

results = []
z_values = []
id_list = []
def processData(df):
        #         df = pd.read_csv(file) 

        # First find the rows where N present that is atom id 64.0 and 65.0
        n1 = np.array(np.where(df.id == 64.0))
        n2 = np.array(np.where(df.id == 65.0))

        # Determine total length of the file i.e number of structures
        lenn1 =n1.size
        lenn2 =n2.size

        # Create list of the N1 and N2 rows 
        n1id = [i.tolist() for i in n1]
        n2id = [j.tolist() for j in n2]

        # Create numpy array of x,y,z of each atom of each row
        df1 = np.array(df[['x','y','z']].loc[n1id[0]])
        df2 = np.array(df[['x','y','z']].loc[n2id[0]])
        # Function to iterate over structures and compute the distance for each pair of rows
        dist_list = []
        for i in np.arange(0,lenn1-1):
                dist = np.linalg.norm(df2[i]-df1[i])
                dist_list.append([i,dist])

        # largest
        # value1=sorted(dist_list,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[0][1]
        # value1_id=sorted(dist_list,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[0][0]

        # # Second largest 
        # value2=sorted(dist_list,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[1][1]
        # value2_id=sorted(dist_list,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[1][0]
        # return value1_id,value1,df1[value1_id], df2[value1_id], value2_id,value2,df1[value2_id], df2[value2_id]

        for i in range(0,10000,100):
                value=sorted(dist_list,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[i][1]
                value_id=sorted(dist_list,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[i][0]
                results.append(value)
                id_list.append(value_id)
                z_values.append(df2[value_id][2])
                re_zip=zip(id_list, results, z_values)
                zip_list = list(re_zip)
        return zip_list
if __name__ == "__main__":
        start_time = time.time()
        file_list = []
        for filename in glob.iglob('/home/ap86/lammps-files/100K/**/*.dump', recursive=True):
                if os.path.isfile(filename):
                        print(filename[:-4])
                        dir=filename[:-10][:-1]
                        os.chdir(dir)
                        print(os.getcwd())
                        bashCommand = "scp -r ../traj.sh ."
                        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                        output, error = process.communicate()
                        bashCommand = "scp -r traj.dump traj.dump.orig"
                        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                        output, error = process.communicate()
                        with open('traj.dump') as f:
                                if 'vx' in f.read():
                                        bashCommand = "bash traj.sh"
                                        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                                        output, error = process.communicate()
                                        df = pd.read_csv('traj.dump', sep='\\s+',names=["id", "type", "x", "y", "z", "vx", "vy", "vz"], dtype=float)
                                        df.to_csv('traj.csv', index=False)
                                else:
                                        bashCommand = "bash traj.sh"
                                        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                                        output, error = process.communicate()
                                        df = pd.read_csv('trajf1.dump', sep='\\s+',names=["id", "type", "x", "y", "z"], dtype=float)
                                        df.to_csv('traj.csv', index=False)
                        df = pd.read_csv('traj.csv')
                        sortedlist = processData(df)
                        print(sortedlist)
                        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: This question is too broad in scope for StackOverflow.  In general, StackOverflow questions are expected to have a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a small bit of code that we can easily copy and run) and a question about a very specific aspect of the provided code. You've provided 94 lines of code, and none of the necessary data to be able to run it.

Comment: @HenryEcker, thanks for your feedback. My intention was not to get a modified code rather some suggestions on how to handle mpi parallel processing. However, I see the problem in my question. Again, thanks for pointing it out. I will edit and repost it.